# NSIS- detect errors found in installation

Tags: installation, nsis

I am using NSIS for creating installers. But i want to get errors happened during installation.Using iferrors at every line or function will be difficult due to length of script etc.So is there any method in NSIS by which i can find errors occurred during installation at least by line number or log or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have is `IfErrors`. You generally only check after `Exec`/`ExecWait` etc.

Create a macro if you want to check after every `File` instruction or whatever your goal is...